# Firebase data not working with datatables

Tags: html, json, firebase, datatables

I am trying to retrieve firebase data and then inserting into tables using the the following code. 
[image]

My output page:
[image]
But my table is only showing the random keys from my "JSON" file on the webpage.The logs are showing keys as well as the data.How can i put the random key with its data in table?

**This is my error message**:

DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0.

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
  var rootRef=firebase.database().ref().child("Orders/")
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

rootRef.on("child_added",snap =>
  {
  var dataSet = [snap.key, snap.val().Nombre];
  table.rows.add([dataSet]).draw();
        console.log(snap.key);
        console.log(snap.val());

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

on your var dataset add all data from firebase you want to put on the data Table, it works

```
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
     var dataSet = [snap.child("name").val(), snap.child("email").val(), snap.child("blood").val(), snap.child("Phone").val(), snap.child("Location").val()];
table.rows.add([dataSet]).draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var dataSet = [snap.key, snap.val().Nombre];
```

To:

```
var dataset = [snap.child("name").val(), snap.val().Nombre];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Topics");
    rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

        var topic_name = snap.child("topic_name").val();
        var uid = snap.child("topic_id").val();
        var downloadURL = snap.child("downloadURL").val();

        $("#tableHeading").append("<tr><td>"+ uid +"</td><td>"+ topic_name +"</td><td><img src='"+downloadURL +"' height='80px' width='80px'/></td><td><button>action</button></td></tr>");
    });
```